# Reading files with fgets()

Tags: c, file

I have a doubt about reading files in C using fgets(). I've seen people use loops in order to do this, but I skip the loop part, doing this instead.

What's the difference between using a loop and my way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file = NULL;
    char string[30];
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r"); //test.txt contains "Hello world!"

    if (file == NULL) {
        puts("ERROR");
        return 1;
    }

    fgets(string, 30, file);

    puts(string);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;

}
```

Outputs:
`Hello world!`

Comment: 1) `fgets(string, 30, file);` is bad.  Use `fgets(string, sizeof string, file);` to avoid mis-stating buffer size.  2) Check the return value from `fgets()` before calling `puts(string);`  3) `puts()` appends another `'\n'`.   Use `fputs(string, stdout);`.

Comment: You should not tag this `C++`.  If you are using `fgets` at all in C++, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: tomasvie, Do you expect `"Hello world!"` to fit in `char string[10];`?

Comment: Even assuming you fix the other problems identified, without a loop, your program will only read (at most) the first line of the file.  It will only read part of the first line if it is too long to fit in the buffer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica — `puts()` adds a newline, which will be an extra newline if the first line of the file is short enough to fit in the buffer.  Using `fputs()` won't add a newline, which would be a problem (of sorts) if the first line is too long.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Disagree not printing a `'\n'` would be a problem.  IAC, OP`s code has many significant short-comings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  — We'll have to agree to disagree on whether the possible absence of a newline is a problem.  I totally agree that there are other significant problems in the code; I was assuming those would be fixed.

Comment: Monica, you're right about the string size. It was a spelling mistake of mine.

Comment: @tomasvie That is why `sizeof string` in `gets(string, sizeof string, file)` is so much better.  No need to maintain `10` or `30` in multiple places.  Also easier to review.

Comment: @tomasvie Poor SO etiquette to change code once answers arrive as it invalidate them.  If needed, _append_ your update.  Question rolled back.

Comment: Often the case with `fgets` is that you really don't need it at all.  One major problem you have is the buffersize mismatch, and the easiest way to avoid that is to use a buffersize of one.  Unless your data is inherently line oriented (often, humans think the data is line oriented when it really isn't), just use `getc` (or `fgetc`, or `getchar`).  Except for the fact that this question is an exercise in using `fgets`, there is no reason to use it at all.  `cat` is best implemented with `getc`.  If you only want to print one line, check when the character read is a newline.  You'll learn more.

Answer (score 1):

**From the man page:**

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s until n-1 bytes are read, or a  is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. A null byte shall be written immediately after the last bytes read into the array.

According to this, fgets stops reading when it encounters a newline, an EOF condition, an input error, or when it has read n - 1 characters. So your approach only reads one line from the file. That's well and good if you need to read only a single line.

To read a whole file line by line, fgets is called in a loop until an EOF condition is reached. Another way would be to read the whole file into a buffer with fread, and then parse it.
Or read it character by character by calling getc in a loop.

EDIT: In your code, fgets is trying to read (n - 1) 29 bytes of memory whereas you allocated only 10 bytes for the buffer. This leads to undefined behaviour. The memory not allocated should not be read. Use sizeof (string) instead.

"Hello World!" can not fit in a buffer you allocated 10 bytes for.

**RETURN VALUE:**

> Upon successful completion, fgets() shall return s.  If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and fgets() shall return a null pointer.  If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, fgets() shall return a null pointer, and shall set errno to indicate the error.

You didn't check the return value of fgets.

Comment: nit (but IMO an important one, so maybe not a "nit").  The line `fgets( ..., 30, ...)` will *not* try to read 30 bytes.  It will read at most 29 bytes and will write up to 30 bytes into the buffer.   The fact that the buffer can only hold 10 is still a significant issue, of course.

Comment: You're correct. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between using a loop and my way?

OP's way has many problems.

**Wrong buffer size**

`fgets(string, 30, file);` overstates the buffer size of 10 allowing *undefined behavior* (UB) due to a potential buffer overflow.

**Input result not checked**

`fgets(string, 30, file);` does not check the return value of `fgets()`.
Until the return value is checked, the contents of `string` are not known to be updated correctly.

**Extra `'\n'`**

`puts(string);` appends an extra `'\n'`.

**The entire file is not certainly read**

A single read might not read the entire contents.  Use a loop.

---

Alternative:  read until `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

```
while (fgets(string, sizeof string, file)) {
  fputs(string, stdout);
}
```